# MVC 5 get current user RoleNames

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Here i need to list the current user roles, for example if i have many roles, like admin,operator,editor,writer etc and one user name(userone) is in tow roles how i will be able to list the roles like :

```
user name : userone 
roles     : editor,writer
```

for that i found this code but is there any simple or better to do:

```
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> RoleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(db));    
            string name = User.Identity.Name;
            string id = UserManager.FindByName(name).Id;
            IList<string> roleNames = UserManager.GetRoles(id);
            string selectedRoleName = "";

            foreach (var item in roleNames)
            {
                ViewBag.selectedRoleName += item + ",";
                selectedRoleName += item + ",";
            }
```

for sure in view you need to call the ViewBag.selectedRoleName

so here if see there is (,) extra in last role name , just searching better way to do it thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to concatenate the rolenames, use `String.Join`:
`string.Join(",", roleNames.ToArray());`

Answer (score 0):

Here is View:

```
    public class UsersAdminController : Controller
{
    public UsersAdminController()
    {
    }

    public UsersAdminController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationRoleManager roleManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        RoleManager = roleManager;
    }

    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    private ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;
    public ApplicationRoleManager RoleManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _roleManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _roleManager = value;
        }
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Details(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

        ViewBag.RoleNames = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);

        return View(user);
    } 
  }
```

And here is view:

```
@model YourApp.Models.ApplicationUser
<div class="page-header">
</div>
<div>
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
<dt>
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
</dt>
<dd>
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserName)
</dd>
</dl>
</div>
<table class="table">
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.RoleNames)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```